# Editing a docked cell created with a notebook

Tags: notebooks, cells, docked-cell

I use the following code to create a new notebook for presentation slides with a docked "banner" cell:

```
With[{mycell = 
   Cell[BoxData[
     RowBox[{ToBoxes[
        Text[Style["Title of talk, Conference, Location, Date", 
             22, Italic, 
             FontColor -> Gray, 
             FontFamily -> "Times"]]]}]], 
    "DockedCell"]}, 
 nb = NotebookCreate[
      ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "SlideShow", 
      DockedCells -> 
        Dynamic[If[
          CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], 
          ScreenStyleEnvironment] === "SlideShow", 
    {Inherited, mycell}, mycell]]]]
```

Then I edit and save the generated notebook as *Presentation1.nb*.

Then I wish to create a new (slide) notebook, *Presentation2.nb*, re-using much of the content of *Presentation1.nb*, so in the Finder I duplicate *Presentation1.nb* and call it *Presentation2.nb* and then open and edit its contents.  How do I also edit the new docked cell's contents in *Presentation2.nb* without having to again generate a new notebook?

Comment: Will editing CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], DockedCells] do what you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SetOptions` directly on any Notebook like this:

```
myNewCell = 
  Cell@RawBoxes@
    ToBoxes@Style["Title of talk, Conference, Location, Date", 22, 
      Italic, FontColor -> Blue, FontFamily -> "Times"];

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> myNewCell]
```

Since DockedCells are not editable but may still contain dynamics, this is another approach:

```
myNewCell = Cell[RawBoxes@ToBoxes@Dynamic@$header];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> myNewCell]

$header = Style["Change me at will", 22,
   Italic, FontColor -> Green, FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

And you can grab the existing one and edit it as well:

```
d = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells];
FullForm@d (*Prints d so you can then edit it*)
altered=Cell[RawBoxes[StyleBox["\"Another Conference, Location, Date\"",14,Italic,FontColor\[Rule]RGBColor[1,0,1],FontFamily\[Rule]"Menlo"]]];
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells -> altered]
```

which now looks like

[image]

Comment: Thanks M. R.  I happen to be traveling for over a week starting tomorrow morning very early and will try running your code when I return.

Comment: Thanks, M. R.  Your code is an improvement upon my methods and very useful (hence +1), but it won't help me with the many slide presentations that I've already made.  I gather that there is no way to edit a docked cell.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I added a bit to my answer, you can edit these cells by reading, then editing, then setting them back.